# Finding my motherboard specification

Tags: memory, motherboard

By use of `lshw` command on Ubuntu 10.04 and Dell Vostro 1015 Core 2 Duo, it reports the following information. How do I find my motherboard specification?

I gather that the specifation points out the detailed memory combinations that can be put in. So where would I find more information.

Googling Dell 047MWF taken from the output does not give anything relevant

```
sl33k@sl33k-laptop:~$ sudo lshw
[sudo] password for sl33k: 
PCI (sysfs)  
sl33k-laptop              
    description: Portable Computer
    product: Vostro 1015
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    serial: G2Y2DN1
    width: 32 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=portable uuid=44454C4C-3200-1059-8032-C7C04F444E31
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 047MWF
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       serial: .G2Y2DN1.CN4864308K3072.
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: A02 (09/17/2009)
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 1984KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pcmcia pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb agp smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6570  @ 2.10GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 400
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.7.10
          serial: 0001-067A-0000-0000-0000-0000
          slot: Microprocessor
          size: 2101MHz
          capacity: 2101MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 200MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe nx x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm ida tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority cpufreq
          configuration: id=0
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 700
             size: 128KiB
             capacity: 128KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back data
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 701
             size: 2MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             clock: 66MHz (15.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal varies unified
        *-logicalcpu:0
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.1
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
        *-logicalcpu:1
             description: Logical CPU
             physical id: 0.2
             width: 64 bits
             capabilities: logical
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 1000
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 2GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
             product: HYMP125S64CP8-S6
             vendor: AD00000000000000
             physical id: 0
             serial: 5043F2AE
             slot: DIMM_A
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR Synchronous [empty]
             physical id: 1
             slot: DIMM_B
             width: 64 bits
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Mobile 4 Series Chipset Memory Controller Hub
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=agpgart-intel
          resources: irq:0
```

Comment: Did you know about [this option at Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/nl/nl/nldhs1/servicetag/G2Y2DN1?s=BIZ) where you can enter your service tag? (That is the serial number `G2Y2DN1` on your laptop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ahsan:

1. Yes, you can add a single 1GB in the empty slot to make it to 3GB or you can add another matching 2GB module (which is 2GB PC2-6400 800MHz memory). Keep in mind it is not mandatory that you ought to match the memory, the only reason is to utilize the dual channel feature.
2. Well, most oft laptops will have OEM motherboards. Only Dell can truly know the exact specification of the motherboard alone but I think the answer to your question is to check the laptop's entire specifications which is similar to the motherboard specification. (ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_vostro_notebook/vostro-1015_Setup%20Guide_en-us.pdf)

For same type of 2GB module you can search for similar memory (PC2-6400 800MHz) mentioned in this website (http://www.memorystock.com/memory/DellVostro1015.html)

P.S: I cannot add comments as i got reputation below 50. This answer is to the questions asked in the comments section.

Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

You could download and install a third-party application like [CPU-G](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cpug/) and see where that gets you.